# Input string was not in the correct format with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting the following exception:

> "Input string was not in the correct format."

I'm taking a Json response which is comma delimited and storing it in a database.  I'm not sure what is wrong.
Here is the code:

```
   foreach (string s in skaters)
            {
                skaterData = s.Split(stringSeparator2, StringSplitOptions.None);
                Console.WriteLine(skaterData[0] + " " + skaterData[1] + " " + skaterData[2] + " " + skaterData[3] + " " + skaterData[4] + " " + skaterData[5] + 
                    " " + skaterData[6] + " " + skaterData[7] + " " + skaterData[8] + " " + skaterData[9] + " " + skaterData[10] + " " + skaterData[11] + " " + skaterData[12]
                    + " " + skaterData[13] + " " + skaterData[14] + " " + skaterData[15]);
                try
                {
                    using (var _temp_Player = new FetcherEntities())
                    {
                        //int validPlayer;
                        //int validTeam;
                        //Skater_Season existingPlayer = _temp_Player.Skater_Season.FirstOrDefault(x => x.player_id == Convert.ToInt32(skaterData[1]) && x.team_id = Convert.ToInt32(skaterData[2]));

                       // if (existingPlayer != null)
                       // {
                         // Console.WriteLine("Existing player: " + existingPlayer.NAME);
                       // }
                       // else
                       // {
                        _temp_Player.Skater_Season.Add(new Skater_Season
                        {
                            player_id = Int32.Parse(skaterData[0]), //stuck here
                            team_id = Int32.Parse(team),
                            season_id = season,
                            Number = Int32.Parse(skaterData[1]),
                            POS = skaterData[2],
                            NAME = skaterData[3],
                            GP = Int32.Parse(skaterData[4]),
                            G = Int32.Parse(skaterData[5]),
                            A = Int32.Parse(skaterData[6]),
                            P = Int32.Parse(skaterData[7]),
                            plusminus = Int32.Parse(skaterData[8]),
                            PIM = Int32.Parse(skaterData[9]),
                            S = Int32.Parse(skaterData[10]),
                            TOIG = skaterData[11],
                            PP = Int32.Parse(skaterData[12]),
                            SH = Int32.Parse(skaterData[13]),
                            GWG = Int32.Parse(skaterData[14]),
                            OT = Int32.Parse(skaterData[15])
                        });
                        try
                        {
                            _temp_Player.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException forwardDB)
                {
                    foreach (DbEntityValidationResult entityError in forwardDB.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (DbValidationError error in entityError.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error Name: {0} : Message: {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Also I've attached some screen shots of what the data looks like.

[image: unparsed data]

[image: parsed data]

Comment: `8470612, 15, C, R. ...` is not a valid `Int32`.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. :(

Comment: if you are not sure what to do @LucaTenuta I would suggest using the debugger and start stepping through the code.. you have written the code and if you see an error or issue in the variables / values that you are working with, then you will need to implement valid conversion and or casting to get the data to not generate the error can you provide variables as well as what line the error is happening on also we would all need to have eagle vision to make out that screen shot.. please post valid input values

Comment: MethodMan, if you right click on the picture and open image in tab you'll get a full size screen shot, I don't know why it posted it that small.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell you exactly where the error is but that message is being thrown by one of the `Int32.Parse` methods receiving data that it cant parse.

The best solution is to use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to gracefully continue if a problem occurs.

Comment: TryParse cannot be used inline as OP is doing here.  The parse would have to happen outside the constructor.

Comment: I can't use TryParse inside the LINQ statement as it won't even build, I'm a beginner and teaching myself, so I said something wrong don't hold it against me.

Comment: In that case I would suggest moving the TryParse outside the constructor, so create a new skaterseason() and then assign the properties after calling the constructor using tryparse, which will allow issues with the data to be caught